# Eclipse App Engine requires Java 1.7 or Later

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am using the google app engine add on for eclipse to create applications. I am on MAC OS X but Eclipse won't let me run any applications and has the error "App Engine requires Java 1.7 or Later ". But my computer has Java 1.7 or later.

Any ideas?

Comment: `java -version`? `which java`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your path is set to point to the correct version of Java [sometimes you may have various versions on your computer].